# How can this jQuery be decoded?

Tags: javascript, decode

I want to know how this jQuery file is encoded, and how can I decode this?

```
var _0xc702 = ["\x66\x6C\x65\x78\x79\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x66\x6E", "\x68\x6F\x72\x69\x7A\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x6C", "\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x64", "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68", "\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x76\x65\x72\x74\x69\x63\x61\x6C", "\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E", "\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x69\x6E\x64\x69\x63\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x75\x6C", "\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E", "\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x69\x6E\x64\x69\x63\x61\x74\x6F\x72\x27\x3E\x2B\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E", "\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x65\x61\x63\x68", "\x6C\x69", "\x66\x69\x6E\x64", "\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65\x27\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x27\x3E\x4D\x45\x4E\x55\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x27\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E", "\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68", "\x75\x73\x65\x72\x41\x67\x65\x6E\x74", "\x6D\x73\x4D\x61\x78\x54\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x50\x6F\x69\x6E\x74\x73", "\x6E\x61\x76\x69\x67\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x20\x74\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74", "\x73\x74\x6F\x70\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x61\x67\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74", "\x68\x72\x65\x66", "\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x61\x74\x74\x72", "\x73\x70\x65\x65\x64", "\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74", "\x73\x74\x6F\x70", "\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x73", "\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74", "\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79", "\x63\x73\x73", "\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65", "\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E", "\x6F\x6E", "\x61", "\x68\x69\x64\x65\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x4F\x75\x74", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x2E\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x20\x74\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x2E\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x73\x74", "\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x62\x69\x6E\x64", "\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x61\x76\x65", "\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x44\x6F\x77\x6E", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x55\x70", "\x6C\x69\x3A\x6E\x6F\x74\x28\x2E\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65\x29", "\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x3A\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E", "\x69\x73", "\x73\x68\x6F\x77", "\x6C\x69\x2E\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x64\x65\x74\x61\x63\x68", "\x75\x6E\x62\x69\x6E\x64", "\x6C\x69\x2C\x20\x61"];
jQuery[_0xc702[1]][_0xc702[0]] = function (_0x99dfx1) {
    var _0x99dfx2 = {
        speed: 300,
        type: _0xc702[2],
        align: _0xc702[3],
        indicator: false,
        hideClickOut: true
    };
    $[_0xc702[4]](_0x99dfx2, _0x99dfx1);
    var _0x99dfx3 = false;
    var _0x99dfx4 = $(this);
    var _0x99dfx5 = window[_0xc702[5]];
    if (_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[6]] == _0xc702[7]) {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[8]](_0xc702[7]);
        if (_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[9]] == _0xc702[10]) {
            $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[8]](_0xc702[10]);
        };
    };
    if (_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[11]] == true) {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[17]](function () {
            if ($(this)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[12]] > 0) {
                $(this)[_0xc702[16]](_0xc702[15]);
            };
        });
    };
    $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[21]](_0xc702[20]);
    _0x99dfx6();
    $(window)[_0xc702[22]](function () {
        if (_0x99dfx5 <= 768 && window[_0xc702[5]] > 768) {
            _0x99dfx10();
            _0x99dfxc();
            _0x99dfx7();
            if (_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[6]] == _0xc702[2] && _0x99dfx2[_0xc702[9]] == _0xc702[10] && _0x99dfx3 == false) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                _0x99dfx3 = true;
            };
        };
        if (_0x99dfx5 > 768 && window[_0xc702[5]] <= 768) {
            _0x99dfx10();
            _0x99dfxb();
            _0x99dfxa();
            if (_0x99dfx3 == true) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                _0x99dfx3 = false;
            };
        };
        _0x99dfx5 = window[_0xc702[5]];
    });

    function _0x99dfx6() {
        if (window[_0xc702[5]] <= 768) {
            _0x99dfxb();
            _0x99dfxa();
            if (_0x99dfx3 == true) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                _0x99dfx3 = false;
            };
        } else {
            _0x99dfxc();
            _0x99dfx7();
            if (_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[6]] == _0xc702[2] && _0x99dfx2[_0xc702[9]] == _0xc702[10] && _0x99dfx3 == false) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                _0x99dfx3 = true;
            };
        };
    };

    function _0x99dfx7() {
        if (navigator[_0xc702[24]][_0xc702[23]](/Mobi/i) || window[_0xc702[26]][_0xc702[25]] > 0) {
            $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[43])[_0xc702[42]](_0xc702[27], function (_0x99dfx8) {
                _0x99dfx8[_0xc702[28]]();
                _0x99dfx8[_0xc702[29]]();
                window[_0xc702[31]][_0xc702[30]] = $(this)[_0xc702[32]](_0xc702[30]);
                $(this)[_0xc702[37]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[35]](true, true)[_0xc702[34]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                if ($(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[39]](_0xc702[38]) == _0xc702[40]) {
                    $(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[35]](true, true)[_0xc702[41]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                } else {
                    $(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[35]](true, true)[_0xc702[34]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                    $(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[35]](true, true)[_0xc702[34]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                };
            });
            if (_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[44]] == true) {
                $(document)[_0xc702[48]](_0xc702[45], function (_0x99dfx9) {
                    if ($(_0x99dfx9[_0xc702[47]])[_0xc702[46]](_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[12]] == 0) {
                        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[34]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                    };
                });
            };
        } else {
            $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[48]](_0xc702[50], function () {
                $(this)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[35]](true, true)[_0xc702[41]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
            })[_0xc702[48]](_0xc702[49], function () {
                $(this)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[35]](true, true)[_0xc702[34]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
            });
        };
    };

    function _0x99dfxa() {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[54])[_0xc702[17]](function () {
            if ($(this)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[12]] > 0) {
                $(this)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[43])[_0xc702[42]](_0xc702[51], function () {
                    if ($(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[39]](_0xc702[38]) == _0xc702[40]) {
                        $(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[52]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                    } else {
                        $(this)[_0xc702[36]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[53]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                    };
                });
            };
        });
    };

    function _0x99dfxb() {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[54])[_0xc702[55]](0);
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[59])[_0xc702[58]](0)[_0xc702[48]](_0xc702[51], function () {
            if ($(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[57]](_0xc702[56])) {
                $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[52]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
            } else {
                $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[54])[_0xc702[53]](_0x99dfx2[_0xc702[33]]);
                $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[59])[_0xc702[58]](0);
            };
        });
    };

    function _0x99dfxc() {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[58]](0);
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[59])[_0xc702[55]](0);
    };

    function _0x99dfxd() {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[18])[_0xc702[8]](_0xc702[10]);
        var _0x99dfxe = $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[18]);
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[14]](_0xc702[54])[_0xc702[60]]();
        for (var _0x99dfxf = _0x99dfxe[_0xc702[12]]; _0x99dfxf >= 1; _0x99dfxf--) {
            $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[16]](_0x99dfxe[_0x99dfxf]);
        };
    };

    function _0x99dfx10() {
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[62])[_0xc702[61]]();
        $(document)[_0xc702[61]](_0xc702[45]);
        $(_0x99dfx4)[_0xc702[19]](_0xc702[13])[_0xc702[55]](0);
    };
};
```

**to clarifying the question:** the above code obfuscated with hex, how to unobfuscate a jQuery code like this to make the code readable.

Comment: Try using http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: This is not jQuery. It may be Javascript.

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0 don't wanna beatifying that :)

Comment: @HoboSapiens - nope, it's jQuery

Comment: @HoboSapiens maybe it's a jquery code but how to decode it?

Comment: @RichardEverett decoding means make the code readable, like other jquery codes...

Comment: @newbie - The first string is a hex representation of [`flexymenu`](http://codecanyon.net/item/flexy-menu-responsive-horizontal-vertical-menu/5059149). Have you bought this product, and are trying to troubleshoot an issue, or are you trying to reverse-engineer it?

Comment: @RichardEverett how did you arrive at `flexymenu`?

Comment: @RichardEverett i just want to learn this type of encoding to make my .js files unreadable like this one...

Comment: @newbie This style is called Javascript obfuscation, and plenty of obfuscatiors are available at https://www.google.com/search?q=js+obfuscator.

Comment: OK, in that case you're looking for a _JavaScript obfuscator_. There are lots out there. Recommending one is not something we can really help you with on SO I'm afraid.

Comment: Here's a little closer -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yyos7keo/1/**, you have to manually replace the array values with the strings

Comment: @Wex Since `\x` is sometimes used to denote a hex value, I figured that `\x66\x6C\x65\x78\x79\x6D\x65\x6E\x75` represented a series of hex values that might be [ASCII character codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). So I pasted this string into the first textbox at http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx, and hit _Convert!_, and then ignored the `?` characters in the converted string.

Comment: @RichardEverett thanks. Discovered that `"\x66\x6C\x65\x78\x79\x6D\x65\x6E\x75".split('\\x')` = `["flexymenu"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting hex -> utf8 then replacing all matches from `_0xc702` with the value from the array. Then replace `\["([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"\]` -> `.$1`. And then quick scan and give semantic variable names.

```
jQuery.fn.flexymenu = function(opts) {
    var options = {
        speed: 300,
        type: "horizontal",
        align: "left",
        indicator: false,
        hideClickOut: true
    };
    $.extend(options, opts);
    var someBool = false;
    var $this = $(this);
    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (options.type == "vertical") {
        $($this).addClass("vertical");
        if (options.align == "right") {
            $($this).addClass("right");
        };
    };
    if (options.indicator == true) {
        $($this).find("li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).children("ul").length > 0) {
                $(this).append("<span class='indicator'>+</span>");
            };
        });
    };
    $($this).prepend("<li class='showhide'><span class='title'>MENU</span><span class='icon'><em></em><em></em><em></em><em></em></span></li>");
    _0x99dfx6();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if (innerWidth <= 768 && window.innerWidth > 768) {
            cleanup();
            _0x99dfxc();
            _0x99dfx7();
            if (options.type == "horizontal" && options.align == "right" && someBool == false) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                someBool = true;
            };
        };
        if (innerWidth > 768 && window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            cleanup();
            _0x99dfxb();
            _0x99dfxa();
            if (someBool == true) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                someBool = false;
            };
        };
        innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    });

    function _0x99dfx6() {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            _0x99dfxb();
            _0x99dfxa();
            if (someBool == true) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                someBool = false;
            };
        } else {
            _0x99dfxc();
            _0x99dfx7();
            if (options.type == "horizontal" && options.align == "right" && someBool == false) {
                _0x99dfxd();
                someBool = true;
            };
        };
    };

    function _0x99dfx7() {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0) {
            $($this).find("a").on("click touchstart", function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
                $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").find("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut(options.speed);
                if ($(this).siblings("ul").css("display") == "none") {
                    $(this).siblings("ul").stop(true, true).fadeIn(options.speed);
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut(options.speed);
                    $(this).siblings("ul").find("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut(options.speed);
                };
            });
            if (options.hideClickOut == true) {
                $(document).bind("click.menu touchstart.menu", function(event) {
                    if ($(event.target).closest($this).length == 0) {
                        $($this).find("ul").fadeOut(options.speed);
                    };
                });
            };
        } else {
            $($this).find("li").bind("mouseenter", function() {
                $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).fadeIn(options.speed);
            }).bind("mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut(options.speed);
            });
        };
    };

    function _0x99dfxa() {
        $($this).find("li:not(.showhide)").each(function() {
            if ($(this).children("ul").length > 0) {
                $(this).children("a").on("click", function() {
                    if ($(this).siblings("ul").css("display") == "none") {
                        $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown(options.speed);
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings("ul").slideUp(options.speed);
                    };
                });
            };
        });
    };

    function _0x99dfxb() {
        $($this).children("li:not(.showhide)").hide(0);
        $($this).children("li.showhide").show(0).bind("click", function() {
            if ($($this).children("li").is(":hidden")) {
                $($this).children("li").slideDown(options.speed);
            } else {
                $($this).children("li:not(.showhide)").slideUp(options.speed);
                $($this).children("li.showhide").show(0);
            };
        });
    };

    function _0x99dfxc() {
        $($this).children("li").show(0);
        $($this).children("li.showhide").hide(0);
    };

    function _0x99dfxd() {
        $($this).children("li").addClass("right");
        var $lis = $($this).children("li");
        $($this).children("li:not(.showhide)").detach();
        for (var length = $lis.length; length >= 1; length--) {
            $($this).append($lis[length]);
        };
    };

    function cleanup() {
        $($this).find("li, a").unbind();
        $(document).unbind("click.menu touchstart.menu");
        $($this).find("ul").hide(0);
    };
};
```

---

Here is some of the code i used to deobfuscate:

**main.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var name = '_0xc702';

var vars;
// Use eval for quick hex -> utf8 strings
eval('vars=' + fs.readFileSync('vars.json', 'utf8'));

var input = fs.readFileSync('input.js', 'utf8');

vars.forEach(function(value, key) {
    input = input.replace(new RegExp(name + '\\['+key+'\\]', 'g'), '"'+ value +'"');
});

input = input.replace(/\["([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"\]/g, '.$1');

console.log(input);
```

**vars.json**

```
["\x66\x6C\x65\x78\x79\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x66\x6E", "\x68\x6F\x72\x69\x7A\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x6C", "\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x64", "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68", "\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x76\x65\x72\x74\x69\x63\x61\x6C", "\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E", "\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x69\x6E\x64\x69\x63\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x75\x6C", "\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E", "\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x69\x6E\x64\x69\x63\x61\x74\x6F\x72\x27\x3E\x2B\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E", "\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x65\x61\x63\x68", "\x6C\x69", "\x66\x69\x6E\x64", "\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65\x27\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x27\x3E\x4D\x45\x4E\x55\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x27\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E", "\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68", "\x75\x73\x65\x72\x41\x67\x65\x6E\x74", "\x6D\x73\x4D\x61\x78\x54\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x50\x6F\x69\x6E\x74\x73", "\x6E\x61\x76\x69\x67\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x20\x74\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74", "\x73\x74\x6F\x70\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x61\x67\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74", "\x68\x72\x65\x66", "\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x61\x74\x74\x72", "\x73\x70\x65\x65\x64", "\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74", "\x73\x74\x6F\x70", "\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x73", "\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74", "\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79", "\x63\x73\x73", "\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65", "\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E", "\x6F\x6E", "\x61", "\x68\x69\x64\x65\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x4F\x75\x74", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x2E\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x20\x74\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x2E\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x73\x74", "\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x62\x69\x6E\x64", "\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x61\x76\x65", "\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x44\x6F\x77\x6E", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x55\x70", "\x6C\x69\x3A\x6E\x6F\x74\x28\x2E\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65\x29", "\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x3A\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E", "\x69\x73", "\x73\x68\x6F\x77", "\x6C\x69\x2E\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x64\x65\x74\x61\x63\x68", "\x75\x6E\x62\x69\x6E\x64", "\x6C\x69\x2C\x20\x61"];
```

**input.js** contained what you had posted except for the first line.

And then running `node main.js > out.js` from the command line

Comment: @newbie just posted a little code to show you how i did it.